# What is the meaning of Thouless energy?

Tags: waves, diffusion, anderson-localization, mesoscopic-physics

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thouless_energy) says "a measure of the sensitivity of energy levels to a change in the boundary conditions of the system", which I don't really understand.

Thouless energy is defined as
$$E_T=\frac{\hbar D}{L^2}$$

How energy levels are associated with this expression? How come this quantity defines some kind of sensitivity? In the context of Anderson localization, $L$ has been taken as the localization length in some references. And $\tau=L^2/D$ is interpreted as diffusion time in a box length $L$. But actually Wiki article says $L$ is the size of the system. I am also confused what $L$ corresponds to in the Thouless energy.

Apparently it also plays role in metal-insulator transition, as I have seen it is used in the dimensionless conductance, but why is that so?